# JSON output from influxdb into dataframe

Tags: r

I fetch data from an influxd time series db, using httr.
Trying to write the nested JSON output from influxdb to an R dataframe. But I can't find a good solution to do that. Is there an idea.

```
{
    "results": [
        {
            "statement_id": 0,
            "series": [
                {
                    "name": "msg.masurement",
                    "columns": [
                        "time",
                        "accMotion",
                        "externalTemperature",
                        "humidity",
                        "pressure",
                        "temperature",
                        "vdd",
                        "x",
                        "y",
                        "z"
                    ],
                    "values": [
                        [
                            "2019-12-21T23:19:40.934538652Z",
                            0,
                            4.5,
                            82,
                            890.958,
                            1.9,
                            3579,
                            59,
                            -3,
                            4
                        ],
                        [
                            "2019-12-21T23:29:40.929648142Z",
                            0,
                            4.5,
                            82,
                            890.868,
                            1.7,
                            3579,
                            59,
                            -3,
                            4
                        ]
                    ]
                }
            ]
```

Comment: try with `jsonlite`

Comment: Using jsonlite, i got an error, Argument 'txt' must be a JSON string, URL or file.

Comment: Can you update the post with your expected output

Comment: fetch data with:         
`> params = list(
+   `pretty` = 'true',
+   `db` = 'ELT_2',
+   `u` = '???',
+   `p` = '???' ,
+   `q` = 'SELECT * FROM "msg.masurement" WHERE time >= now() - 30m'
+ )
> json_file <- httr::GET(url = 'http://123.456.789.33:8086/query', query = params)`, and after, using jsonlite I got this: `> fromJSON(json_file, simplifyDataFrame = TRUE)
Fehler: Argument 'txt' must be a JSON string, URL or file.`

Comment: Did you look at the [influxdbr](https://github.com/dleutnant/influxdbr) package ?